# What causes Rich Test Resuls to read different values that I what see in Chrome/Firefox inspect element?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, review, vue-storefront

I have a critical issue with Google Rich Test Results:

**Value in property "reviewCount" must be posivie**
The console shows this code:

`<meta data-v-f499eefe="" itemprop="reviewCount" content="0" />`

`<meta data-v-f499eefe="" itemprop="ratingValue" content="5" />`

and on the page I tesed, the code is the following:

`<meta data-v-f499eefe="" itemprop="reviewCount" content="5">`

`<meta data-v-f499eefe="" itemprop="ratingValue" content="5">`

I Tried checking with different browsers, but all showed me the correct value,

`reviewCount" content="5"`

I use a PWA as frontend.